# Sign ambiguity of two diagrams in Mahan's book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, conventions, feynman-diagrams

In Mahan's book 'Many-particle Physics' 3rd Ed., Eq. (3.213) on page 135 gives a sign rule for Matsubara Green's functions $$(-1)^{m+F}$$ where $F$ is the number of fermion loops and $m$ is the order, i.e., number of internal (phonon) lines for electron self-energy; and half the number of interaction vertices for phonon self energy. Then it quickly gives two example diagrams with both '+' signs in Eqs. (3.214, 3.215).
Solid line: electron. Dashed: phonon. Wavy: external electromagnetic field (not really entering the formula and not relevant to my question, I suppose).

[image]

However, it is not readily clear to me how the sign rule is applied here. It looks like we have (a) $m=1,F=1$ (b) $m=2,F=1$ and hence (a) '+' and (b) '-'. What is wrong here?

BTW, I feel it is not just a typo: I tried the direct Wick contraction myself and it seems to agree with Mahan's signs in the equations.

---

Just in case, the equations are
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax for the equations...

Answer (score 0):

1. For what it's worth, the factor can in principle be derived from the Feynman rules, cf. OP's related [Phys.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/777780/2451). If we compare the non-zero temperature factor
   $$ \left(\frac{-1}{\beta \nu}\right)^m(-(2S+1))^F \tag{3.213} $$
   with the zero-temperature factor
   $$ \left(\frac{i}{2\pi \nu}\right)^m(-(2S+1))^F, \tag{2.127} $$
   it suggests that the sign factor mentioned by OP can be viewed as a result of [Wick-rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) $\beta=i\Delta t$. The bounded time interval $\Delta t$ gets replaced with the value $2\pi$ in the unbounded case. Here $\nu$ denotes the spatial 3D volume.
2. On p. 91 in Ref. 1 the meaning of the exponent $m$ is mention

   - under point (a) for electron self-energy: $m=\#$ of internal boson lines.
   - under point (b) for phonon self-energy: $2m=\#$ of vertices.
   - but seemingly not for photon self-energy relevant for Fig. 3.5. Instead the text on p. 91 refers more generally to Section 2.10.

References:

1. G.D. Mahan, *Many-Particle Physics,* 2000; eqs. (2.127) + (3.213).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think so. 1. If we do the Wick contraction, we will find these two diagrams of the same relative sign (overall sign is more of a matter of convention and not our concern). For the derivation, see the A and C diagrams/terms in [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/777780/20564). 2. The relative sign between B,C,D from that derivation is consistent with Mahan's sign rule, at least suggesting the derivation is in the correct spirit. And A there or the 1st diagram here, which is the simplest, is more straightforward to check, but I couldn't spot an error.

Comment: **So direct Wick contraction calculation gives the same sign for the two diagrams here, consistent with Mahan's explicit equations but contradicting his sign rule.** Although the text does not explicitly mention photon self-energy, I think it should also apply. Otherwise, it would be very weird to show such examples right below the rule.